# Accessing io object in app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have an application built on express. I have an app.js that starts the app, and a functions.js where I have stored a lot of the functionality of the app. I would like to be able to access the socket.io object to use in my functions.js. However, it seems that I cannot do this and I can't find any solution on the internet either.

app.js:

`var app = express(); //var app = express.createServer();
var http = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);`

functions.js:

`//something like io = require('./app').io`

I want to be able to access the io object so I can emit messages to my client side javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use `module.exports` to make the io object available to other modules.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3001);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.io = io;
module.exports = app;

require('./functions')
```

functions.js:

```
var io = require('./app').io;
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('a user connected');
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, I have to export the app from app.js 
`module.exports = app` in order for `npm start` to work. I tried altering the www file so that I was able to export more than just the app but I had no luck. I'm not sure where to go from here. Or if npm start is worth using?

Comment: You can add `io` as a property on the `app` object. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Ok so I have:
app.js:
`var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.io = io;
module.exports = app;`
and in functions.js:

`var io = require('./app').io;
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});`
but I get the following error: **Cannot call method 'on' of undefined**

Comment: An immediate suggestion would be to try adding it to the app.locals object, as specified in the API reference for Express (http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html).

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the help but I am getting a similar error.